# How to replace values in Pandas columns only if RegEx condition is matched

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'c1' : ['31', '421', 'sgdsgd', '523.3'],
    'c2' : ['41', np.nan, '412', '412'],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to replace all values to `np.nan` if they are not float:

```
0   31      41   1
1   421     NaN  2
2   NaN     412  3
3   523.3   412  4
```

here what I do:

```
df_test[['c1', 'c2']] = df_test[['c1', 'c2']].replace(to_replace=r'^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$', value=np.nan, regex=True)
```

But result is not what I am looking for:

```
0   NaN     NaN  1
1   NaN     NaN  2
2   sgdsgd  NaN  3
3   NaN     NaN  4
```

Comment: You have the sense inverted. That `.replace()` will turn numbers into `NaN`, but you explained that you want to turn non-numbers into `NaN`. Just use `.to_numeric()` and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors="coerce"`:

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’ :
>
> - If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
> - If ‘**coerce**’, then invalid parsing will be set as **NaN**.
> - If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

```
df_test = df_test.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df_test)
      c1     c2  test
0   31.0   41.0     1
1  421.0    NaN     2
2    NaN  412.0     3
3  523.3  412.0     4
```

Comment: Nice solution! You can make it even more concise with `df_test.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")` since keyword args passed to `apply` get passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks fsimonjetz, I updated my answer ;)